# NLP: any classification method about sentence semantics, sentence completeness, and question generation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language

I come across some interesting areas in natural language processing (NLP) and I am trying to find resources on them. Do you know is there any existing method/research on these NLP areas:

1. sentence completeness: whether a sentence is a complete sentence.
   e.g., "I am a boy" vs "I am boy" OR "Who are you?" vs "Who you?"
2. semantic classification: whether the sentence make sense.
   e.g., "The dog run" vs "The dog flies"
3. question generation: can I generate questions from a sentence.
   e.g., "I am a King and I rule the space." --> "Who is King?" "Can king rule the space?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To some degree, the first two come for free with language modeling.

In language modeling, we attempt to maximize $E[P(X_{1..T})]$ where $X_{1..T}$ is a sequence of words sampled from our dataset, and $P(X_{1..T})$ is our model. Usually we factor $P(X_{1..T})$ as:

$$P(X_{1..T}) = \prod_{t=0}^T P_\theta(x_t|x_{<t})$$ where $P_\theta(x_t|x_{<t})$ is typically a recurrent neural network.

- Sentence completion: given the start of a sentence $x_{1..k}$ simply sample $X_k \sim P_\theta(x_k|x_{<k})$, then increment $k$ and repeat until encountering an end-of-sentence symbol.
- Semantic classification: simply check using a standard parser whether the sentence is syntactically valid. If it is, then you can say the next word is semantically valid if $\frac{P_\theta(x_k = X_k|x_{<k})}{\max_X P_\theta(x_k = X|x_{<k})}$ is above a certain threshold. Of course if your corpus is filled with semantically invalid statements, then this will fail. This procedure rests on the assumption that semantically valid statements have a reasonable chance of being written down.